# Scala 2.11.5 compiler crash with type aliases and manifests

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-alias

It appears that passing an alias to a wild-carded parameterized type to a function that tries to get an implicit `Manifest` for the type will crash the Scala 2.11.5 compiler.

The following can be pasted in the 2.11.5 REPL to reproduce the crash:

```
class C[T]
def f[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) = 0

type CAlias = C[_]
val x = f[CAlias]
```

The crash output is very verbose, but contains this info:

```
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
  ?MethodType?
     while compiling: <console>
        during phase: globalPhase=erasure, enteringPhase=posterasure
     library version: version 2.11.5
    compiler version: version 2.11.5
  reconstructed args:

  last tree to typer: type $iw
       tree position: line 9 of <console>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: object $iw
   symbol definition: class $iw extends Object (a ModuleClassSymbol)
      symbol package: $line10
       symbol owners: object $iw -> object $iw -> object $read
           call site: object $iw in package $line10
```

There are several conditions for this crash. The type `C` must be parameterized. The alias must use a wildcard (`C[_]`). The call must use a type alias, just calling `f[C[_]]` works fine.

In my program the case is far more complex, and the only solution I've found is to have the method not accept a `Manifest`, but just take a `Class` parameter instead, which is ugly.

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions for better workaround? I didn't see a bug in the Scala bug tracker, so if this seems legit, I'll go ahead and report it.

Comment: For reference, I've created https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9155 to track this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag` (or `scala.reflect.ClassTag` if it's sufficient; since you mention taking `Class` as an option, it may be) instead of `Manifest`. They are inserted as implicit arguments by the compiler in the same way as `Manifest`s are. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html for more. In particular, note

> In Scala 2.10, scala.reflect.ClassManifests are deprecated, and it is planned to deprecate scala.reflect.Manifest in favor of TypeTags and ClassTags in an upcoming point release.

You probably should still report the bug; even if it's marked as wont-fix, it'll help people who stumble over this in the future.

Comment: Awesome, that basically does do what I want. It's interesting that the TypeTag actually gets information about the alias. To get the class, I have to call .erasure on it, but that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: Oops... I think I spoke too soon. I need java reflection objects (like java.lang.Class or java.lang.reflect.Type). I'm having trouble figuring out how to get those from the scala Types.

Comment: You can use `typeTag.mirror.runtimeClass(typeTag.tpe)` to get a `Class`. I don't know about `java.lang.reflect.Type`; you may want to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I've reaccepted this and it ended up working. I also asked another question about getting Types, though it seems like not be possible at the moment.

Comment: Also, if just getting the `Class` is good enough, you can use `ClassTag` and `classTag.runtimeClass`.